# Is there a way to retrieve the original message with the `reply_to_id` from `Action.Submit`?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

Using AdaptiveCard, I can get the `reply_to_id` after clicking on a button implemented with `Action.Submit`. But this ID seems to be different from the ID of the original message. How can I track it back to the original message?

Comment: Could you please look into this sample-https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/42db6e453ce67e26c80996494d32f18aacbc019a/samples/bot-conversation/csharp/Bots/TeamsConversationBot.cs#L246